# XY Chart dynamically line series using dataSource

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using [amcharts4](https://www.amcharts.com) to display some charts using *vanilla* javascript and a .Net Core API to get the data (on json format).

I need to create a Line Chart (*XY chart*) with a category X axis (time) and a value Y axis (temperatures).
The chart must contain dynamically series (I don't know in advanced how much series will be) and get the data using *dataSource*.

I can't find the way to get it working.

I have already read all of the documentation, guides and examples that have found about this:
 - [List templates](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/list-templates/)
 - [Adapters](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/)
 - [XY-charts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/xy-chart/)
 - [DataSource](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/datasource/)
 - [Dynamically adding and removing series](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/dynamically-adding-and-removing-series/)
 - [Line series](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/lineseries/)
 - [Series](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/series/)

And here on SO I only found this [Stacked Area Amchart passing dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854401/stacked-area-amchart-passing-dynamic-data) (all the other post I can find aren't about amcharts**4**). But I need both using dataSource to get the data and have dynamically added series simultaneously.

I can modify the API to change the json data structure.
I'm using the javascript way to define the charts and series.

I already tried to add an event when the *datasource* load the data ("*load*" event),and in that function I parse the data of the chart, separated in different arrays, make the json with all the pairs (value, timestamp) for each serie and then create the series dynamically. But it didn't work, the *Legend* of the serie load properly but the data never appears.
I also have set the error event of the *datasource* but no errors appear (in the browser console either).

I can't find the way of using *dataSource* and have dynamically Line series, may be there are a simple way of doing this using amchart but can't get it.

Thank you!

---

Data example:

```
[
{
    "deviceName": "device1",
    "dateTime": "30/12/2019 0:45:12",
    "value": "35"
},
{
    "deviceName": "device2",
    "dateTime": "30/12/2019 0:45:12",
    "value": "30"
},
{
    "deviceName": "device3",
    "dateTime": "30/12/2019 0:45:12",
    "value": "20"
},
{
    "deviceName": "device4",
    "dateTime": "30/12/2019 0:45:12",
    "value": "23"
},
{
    "deviceName": "device1", (---> again)
    "dateTime": "30/12/2019 1:15:12",
    "value": "36"
},

(...),

{
    "deviceName": "device4",
    "dateTime": "30/12/2019 12:18:51",
    "value": "29"
}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

You might find [`done`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/datasource/#done_event) to be a more appropriate event as you know that the parse/load is successful at this point. Not knowing exactly what you tried to do in your attempt since you didn't post your code, you might not be setting up your series correctly with the correct X and Y data fields.

The following works correctly for me:

```
chart.dataSource.url = "/path/to/your/data/payload";
chart.dataSource.events.on('done', function(ev) {
  var data = ev.data;
  var chart = ev.target.component;

  //the following assumes all series value fields are present 
  //in the first element in your array.
  Object.keys(data[0]).filter(function(item) {
    return item !== 'year'; //filter out non-series value fields
  }).forEach(function(valueField) { 
    //create your series
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries);
    series.name = valueField;
    series.dataFields.categoryX = 'year';
    series.dataFields.valueY = valueField;
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f920d0f7c325ad513ca365643e16a6db?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks @xorspark, it was my mistake that I didn't specify that I cannot assume all series value fields are present in the first element of my array (but I can manage it adding a function that get all the series names), but your complete example give me some clues, thanks!. I have edited my question to put an example of the data. Also, i need to update the data (using "reloadFrequency"), I tried to remove an re add the series but isn't working, can you give me some advice about how to do it? thank you!!

Comment: Since you said you can modify the API, i think it would be much easier to do that and group your data by date like in my example instead of your current structure. Your current structure would involve you writing more JS to do stuff that would be more efficient in the backend. I also don't see why you would need to remove/re-add series; just loop through the series and check if the device name exists in the series. You'll want to write a funciton that scans your data for any new valueFields and use that in your update logic in the done event. Does that make sense?